# What regular expression do I need to accept no spaces in a textbox?

Tags: jquery

This is my password validation code.

Other than space I wanted to accept everything in this textbox. This is my validation code.

```
$("#clientPassWord").on("change", function() {
  var clientPassWord = $("#clientPassWord").val().length;
  var clientPassWord1 = $("#clientPassWord").val();
  if (clientPassWord == null || clientPassWord <= 0) {
    $("#passmsg").show();
    $("#passmsg").html("This is a required field. You can’t leave it empty.");
  } else {
    if (clientPassWord >= 8) {
      $("#passmsg").hide();
      $("#joinbtn").removeAttr('disabled');
      if (clientPassWord1.toLowerCase().match("paperindex") || clientPassWord1.toUpperCase().match("PAPERINDEX") || clientPassWord1.toLowerCase().match("paperindexcom") || clientPassWord1.toUpperCase().match("PAPERINDEXCOM")) {
        $("#passmsg").show();
        $("#passmsg").html("&quot;PaperIndex&quot; and variations of this word are not allowed here");
      } else {
        $("#passmsg").hide();
        $("#joinbtn").removeAttr('disabled');
      }

    } else {
      $("#passmsg").show();
      $("#passmsg").html("Short passwords are easy to guess. Enter at least 8 characters.");
      $("#joinbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check if space (' ') is present in the textbox value.

```
$("#clientPassWord").on("change", function () {
var clientPassWord=$("#clientPassWord").val().length;
var clientPassWord1=$("#clientPassWord").val();
if(clientPassWord==null || clientPassWord<=0){
$("#passmsg").show();
$("#passmsg").html("This is a required field. You can’t leave it empty.");
}
else if($("#clientPassWord").val().indexOf(' ') >= 0){
$("#passmsg").show();
$("#passmsg").html("Spaces are not allowed!!!");
}
else{
if(clientPassWord>=8 ) {
$("#passmsg").hide();
$("#joinbtn").removeAttr('disabled'); 
if (clientPassWord1.toLowerCase().match("paperindex") || clientPassWord1.toUpperCase().match("PAPERINDEX") || clientPassWord1.toLowerCase().match("paperindexcom") || clientPassWord1.toUpperCase().match("PAPERINDEXCOM") ) {                    
$("#passmsg").show();
$("#passmsg").html("&quot;PaperIndex&quot; and variations of this word are not allowed here");
}  
else{
            $("#passmsg").hide();
         $("#joinbtn").removeAttr('disabled');
         }                           

}
else {
    $("#passmsg").show();
$("#passmsg").html("Short passwords are easy to guess. Enter at least 8 characters.");
$("#joinbtn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    }

    }        
});
```

Comment: Thank You so very much! it worked absolutely finev:)